# Thin data set to reduce size but retain meaning algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-science

I'm gathering data from load sensors at about 50Hz. I might have 2-10 sensors running at a time. This data is stored locally but after a period of about a month it needs to be uploaded to the cloud. The data during this one second can vary quite significantly and is quite dynamic.

It's too much data to send because its going over GSM and signal will not always be great.

The most simplistic approach I can think of is to look at the 50 data points in 1 sec and reduce it to just enough data to make a box and whisker graph. Then, the data stored in the cloud could be used to create dashboards that look similar to how you look at stocks. This would at least show me the max, min, average and give some idea around the distribution of the load during that second.

This is probably over simplified though so I was wondering if there was a common approach to this problem in data science...  take a dense set of data and reduce it to still capture the highlights and not lose its meaning.

Any help or ideas appreciated

Comment: This is usually called sketching.

Comment: Seems like [datascience.se] suite this question better.. have a try. ( :